# ExpansionTile is overflowing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to wrap some list items in an Expansion panel But the contents are overflowing.

```
      ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('Client'),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: upComingCompliancesList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                          color: buttonColor,
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(upComingCompliancesList[index].name==null? upComingCompliancesList[index].name==null : ' '),
                            subtitle: Text(
                                '${upComingCompliancesList[index].label} at ${upComingCompliancesList[index].date}'),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

It is showing the following error:

The following assertion was thrown during layout:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 277 pixels on the bottom.

the following error is shown on the screen:
[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ExpansionTile in a scrollable Widget to compensate for its content when the ExpansionTile is in an expanded state. Use 'SingleChildScrollView' like so:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
     child: ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('Client'),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: upComingCompliancesList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                          color: buttonColor,
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(upComingCompliancesList[index].name==null? upComingCompliancesList[index].name==null : ' '),
                            subtitle: Text(
                                '${upComingCompliancesList[index].label} at ${upComingCompliancesList[index].date}'),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
     ),
```